# How to make Hangfire api calls with jwt token

Tags: .net-6.0, hangfire

I have a Hangfire job which runs on.Net Core 6 Api, I create jobs on hangfire to make the api calls. My api has jwt token authentication, so when my recurring job is running, it makes an api call and this call should be with a jwt token. I can not figure out how to do it, does anybody have any idea ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What have you implemented so far that's not working?

Comment: public async Task<BorsaResponse<bool>> ReccuringJob(int id)
        {
            var token = "myjwttoken";

   var loggedUserId = _borsaContext.UserId();


            return response;
        }

Comment: You hangfire jobs should use client credentials flow or API_KEY. If they are on the same host - not sure why do you need to call API ?